# Django counting related objects in model layer

Tags: django, average, vote

It is possible to do something like this working:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    vote = models.IntegerField() # summary of all votes
    def average_vote(self):
        return int(vote/self.annotate(Count('voters')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
class Book(models.Model):
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
    vote = models.IntegerField() # summary of all votes

    def average_vote(self):
        return int(self.vote/self.voters.all().count())
```

Let me know if that works. I haven't tested it.

Comment: I will try this, but I need other things in code to do before I could check all. But I answet You.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the default manager to make it always return an annotated queryset:

```
class BookUserManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(BookUserManager, self).get_query_set(*args, **kwargs).annotate(average_vote=models.Avg('books__vote'))

class BookUser(User):
    objects = BookUserManager()

    class Meta:
        proxy = True

class Book(models.Model):
    # Next line has been changed to use proxy model. This *will* affect the m2m table name.
    voters = models.ManyToManyField(BookUser, blank=True, related_name='books')
    vote = models.IntegerField() # summary of all votes

    objects = BookManager()
```

Then, you can get at the value like any other attribute on your the user model:

```
user = BookUser.objects.get(username='joe')
print user.average_vote
```

**Update:** Sorry... got that all wrong. That's what I get for reading the question too quickly. You'd actually need to annotate `User` not `Book`, but since `User` is coming from `django.contrib.auth` (I'm assuming) that's not going to be possible, or at least it requires more steps. Code above has been updated.